# Use of DerivativeStructure in Apache Commons Math

Tags: java, apache-commons-math

I am having a hard time understanding how to use [DerivativeStructure](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/differentiation/DerivativeStructure.html) in Apache Commons Math.

I have a [Logit](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/function/Logit.html) function for which I would like to get the first order derivative. Then I would like to get the value of that derivative on multiple distinct values.

```
Logit logit = new Logit(0.1, 10.0);
DerivativeStructure ds =   // How to instanctiate?
DerivativeStructure dsRes = logit.value(ds);
// How to use dsRes to get the value of the derivative function applied on
// several values?
```

In addition, if there is any document describing how to use that DerivativeStructure, I am highly interested!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How about referring to JavaDocs: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/differentiation/DerivativeStructure.html

Comment: Well I read it but it appears it is not descriptive enough for me to use it. I tried a few things to test it but it has remained unsuccessful. I believe my use case is easy enough not to have to read a full paper to come to a solution. I would have liked the Javadoc to give just a few examples so that a new comer can use it confidently after reading them.

Comment: Have you read the [user guide on Numerical Analysis, section 4.7](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/analysis.html)? As far as I can tell it gives a decent introduction to differentiation using `DerivativeStructure`.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson Great! I did not see it myself... Add this as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: Glad it helped, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Apache Commons Math [User Guide](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/index.html), the section on Numerical analysis [Differentiation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/analysis.html#a4.7_Differentiation), there is a reasonable introduction on how to apply the [DerivativeStructure](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/differentiation/DerivativeStructure.html).